# how do I know if my sort worked in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I recorded the following macro when sorting data:

```
Sub sort_sheet_test()
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Range("A1:AB40905").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("flurry_an_output.csv").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("flurry_an_output.csv").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("AB2:AB40905"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("flurry_an_output.csv").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:AB40905")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I then wrote my own function to use generically in other sheets...etc:

```
Function sort_sheet_last_column(sheet_name As String)

    Dim rows1 As Long
    rows1 = Get_Rows_Generic(sheet_name, 1) '  get the number of rows in the sheet

    Dim columns1 As Integer
    columns1 = Range(find_last_column(sheet_name)).column ' get the number of columns in the sheet

    Dim sort_range As Range
    Dim key_range As Range
    With Worksheets(sheet_name)
        Set sort_range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rows1, columns1)) ' set up range: the whole used portion of the sheet
        Set key_range = .Range(.Cells(1, columns1), .Cells(rows1, columns1))
    End With

    With Worksheets(sheet_name).Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=key_range, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange sort_range
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With

End Function
```

It seems to reorder the rows based on the right key, but how do I know if my version is 1) working at all (it's hard to know if over 40,000 rows are ordered properly, and 2) how do I know if the rest of the data are in their proper order?

Answer (score 0):

I always use Sheet.Range.Sort not Sheet.Sort

```
 lLastRow = LastUsedRow(shMain)

 shMain.Range("A1:W" & lLastRow).SORT Key1:=.Range("B2"), _
                                      Order1:=xlAscending, _
                                      Header:=xlYes, _
                                      OrderCustom:=1, _
                                      MatchCase:=False, _
                                      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                                      DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Never had a problem with this sorting the range and you can add Key2,Order2 and DataOption2 to sort by multiple columns